# Unable to locate the Search Box element on Google Home Page using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Why i am getting this error?:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#gbqfq"}
```

This is the code i am using to open the browser and search for a given word in google search:

```
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
element.SendKeys("APPLES");

// Get the search results panel that contains the link for each result.
IWebElement resultsPanel = driver.FindElement(By.Id("search"));

// Get all the links only contained within the search result panel.
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> searchResults = resultsPanel.FindElements(By.XPath(".//a"));

// Print the text for every link in the search results.
int resultCNT = 1;
foreach (IWebElement result in searchResults)
{
    if (resultCNT <= 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    resultCNT ++;
}
```

Does somebody know what could be the issue?Thanks

Full Log:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#gbqfq"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at $Program.$Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\gabri\source\repos\Example\Example\Program.cs:line 10
```

Comment: Are you sure the page is loaded? What does PageSource return? On https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/getting-started-with-webdriver-in-c-using-visual-studio is an example for waiting till an element is found.

Comment: it opened google search in google chrome but that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your usecase is to open the browser and search for a given word within [Google Home Page](http://google.com), the *Search Box* HTML is as follows:

```
<input class="gLFyf gsfi" maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text" jsaction="paste:puy29d" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" title="Search" value="" aria-label="Search" data-ved="0ahUKEwiq_ZvUyJvrAhXhzjgGHXBjBx4Q39UDCAQ">
```

So to identify the `<input>` box you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Name*:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("gbqfq");
  ```
- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[name='q']")).SendKeys("APPLES");
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@name='q']")).SendKeys("APPLES");
  ```

Moreover, the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to send a *character sequence* within the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following *ocator Strategies*:

- *Name*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("q"))).SendKeys("APPLES");
  ```
- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("[name='q']"))).SendKeys("APPLES");
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@name='q']"))).SendKeys("APPLES");
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I changed my code to `driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("gbqfq");` and it worked but i'm getting the same error now when i try get the search results using `IWebElement resultsPanel = driver.FindElement(By.Id("search"));`

Comment: That sounds to be a all together a different requirement. Can you raise a new question for your  new requirement please?

Comment: Oh ok no problem

Comment: Thanks for you help!